# Telling whether contentText is going to be ellipsized

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

In order to decide whether or not to use the BitTextStyle of an Android notification I would like to know if there is a way to tell if the OS is going to ellipsize the contentText of the notification (because is too long) or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like this:

```
int length = (tv.getText() == null) ? 0 : tv.getText().length();
int width = tv.getWidth()-tv.getPaddingLeft()-tv.getPaddingRight();

if (tv.getTextSize() * length > width) {
    Log.e("TAG", "Ellipsize: TRUE");
} else {
    Log.e("TAG", "Ellipsize: FALSE");
}
```

*Notes:*

- Please test it yourself, it's only from the top of my head :)
- Must do it once the TextView has been drawn.

**Edit:**

I found out that the method `hasOverlappingRendering()` works pretty nicely for this.

Returns true if the text doesn't fit in the TextView, however is only for **API 16+**.

Comment: That looks nice, only if I knew how to obtain the TextView out of the Notification object...